# How to use decodeBitmap?

Tags: java, android

I'm using, in my app, a library called natario1/CameraView so I can implement a camera to my fragment. The camera shows just right. The problem is, in the method to decode the Bitmap of the photo taken, there is this line of code:

```
cmrView.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPictureTaken(byte[] picture) {
       super.onPictureTaken(picture);
       btnfoto.setText("boas");
       CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(picture);
   }
});
```

This `CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(picture);` is giving me an error because it expects another expression. When I make `CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(picture,);` it says " byte[]source,**BitmapCallback callback** ". I'm noob in android. Can you explain what I need to do now so I can retrieve the pictures taken by the user?

Comment: Can you tell what error comes when you calling **CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(picture);** and to call another method you are supposed to add a callback variable

Comment: You mean the log file?

Comment: error: no suitable method found for decodeBitmap(byte[])
method CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(byte[],BitmapCallback) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(byte[],int,int,BitmapCallback) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(byte[],int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Yes i figured that out look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51060137/9734616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(picture);**

This method no longer exists in the CameraUtils.

If you want a bitmap They have provided you another way like

```
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] picture) {
        super.onPictureTaken(picture);
        CameraUtils.decodeBitmap(picture, new CameraUtils.BitmapCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                //Here comes your bitmap
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Now, when I click my "shoot" button, the app crashes ahah

Comment: try to add this in your gradle file **compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.+'**

Comment: Well, you rock mate. Thanks alot!

Comment: it is laggy when use it to save the image is that happens with you?

Answer (score 0):

add this library to your Gradle, it will help clean up your code a little bit :

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

then to save your picture do like this :

```
Camera.PictureCallback picture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File imageFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), "image.png");
        try {
            FileOutputStream imageFileStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            IOUtils.write(data, imageFileStream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(imageFileStream);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};
```

to retrieve the picture do like this :

```
 File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/image.png");
        try {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileUtils.openInputStream(file));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: So basically I remove what I have (what is in the question) and replace with like that?

Comment: yep ! using `getExternalCacheDir` will save the picture temporarily so that you avoid using too much memory especially when you have big pictures.. and In general saving a picture and calling it with it's absolute path is better than carrying the whole picture between the activities.. that will help speed your app.. give it a try and see if it works

Comment: Sweet. Can you just tell me what does this `Intent intent = new Intent("takePicture");` do?

Comment: my bad. It's a line from my code I forgot to delete.. I edited my answer